# ROS package checked out from SVN. Can't build it on eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, svn, makefile, ros

I've checked out a ROS package that I have on my repository on a different PC (ubuntu).
The problem is that while rosmake (or make for that matter) from cli, in eclipse it gives me the following error.

/usr/bin/make all 
rospack: error while loading shared libraries: librospack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile:1: /cmake.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/cmake.mk'.  Stop.

I suppose it's problem is eclipse's build enviroment. How do I debug this?
Shouldn't it work out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that because I was running eclipse from an icon it couldn't get the environment variables. I had to change the link to bash -i -c eclipse.